# Regarding how TLB and Cache are different in a typical program

Tags: caching, memory-management, operating-system, tlb

A typical has 20% memory instructions.Assume there are 5% data TLB misses,each requires 100 cycles to handle.Assume each instruction requires 1 cycle to execute,each memory operation in the cache 1 cycle,10% of data access are cache misses each cache miss is 15 cycle, So how long would it take to execute 1000 instruction.

I don't know the answer but I am confused with prsence of both TLB and cache, I was under impression that cache and TLB are the same thing?

Comment: Did you read e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache?

Answer (score 0):

They are two very different things...

Simply enough, a TLB contains only *addresses* (TLBs are needed to speed up the translation of virtual addresses) while a cache can contain whatever (that is, memory of any kind, code or data).

Comment: Thanks all of you ,I did some questions and got the concept .

Answer (score 0):

Overhead on Cache-misses = 14cycles

Overhead on TLB-miss = 99cycles

cache misses = 1000 * 20% * 10% = 20

TLB misses = 1000 * 20% * 5% = 10

Total cycles      = 1000 cycles + (overhead due to cache misses) + (overhead due to TLB misses)

```
                = 1000 + (20 * 14) + (10 * 99) = 1000 + 280 + 990 = 2270 cycles
```